# listen to camera events android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to implement camera events in android. I am a newbie at this. How exactly does one go about listening to events like didCancel and didFinishPickingMedia? please advise. I am quite desperate as a quick search has not been able to lead me anywhere.

Comment: I am not too sure what it is you are asking. Are you trying to interact directly with the camera hardware and capture photos? Or are you trying to create a point in your code that opens the camera application on the device and asks it to give you a photo. If it's the second there are a few intents you just have to send to startActivityForResult with and you should be able to get the Cancelled callback or the Bitmap URI returned. But both are very different so can't really help until then.

Comment: Hey Greg, I am actually trying to interact directly with the hardware. Could you advise me on how I should proceed?

Comment: I would check out Balaji's links then. Everything is done through the SurfaceHolder. So you end up getting callbacks through this virtual canvas. However I don't think there is any didFinishPickingMedia, you would have to interact with the MediaStore for that.

Comment: Greg, what about the didCancel? I am sure it is similar to closing the shutter or closing the camera functionality. Are you familiar with a listener I could implement for such an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you are looking for this:

[MediaStore ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

If you create an intent with this:

```
Uri uri = ... // where I want a full sized photo to be.
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CALLBACK_ID);
```

Then somewhere in the same activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int  requestId, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestId == MY_CALLBACK_ID) {
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED) {
       onCancelled();
   } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      onFinishedPickingMedia();
   }
}
```

or if you really just want the Gallery to just show up, you might be able to get away with similar code, except that instead of using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, try this (I haven't verified it):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CALLBACK_ID);
```

I don't think the specific callbacks you are asking for exist in Android. Where have you heard them referenced?

Comment: Thanks Greg, Let me try this implementation. The events I am referring to are ios native. I just wanted to implement them in android. IT seems to be quite a pickle though!!

Comment: No prob, I am sorry I don't know iOS. Can you point me to some documentation? I think though you don't want to manage the whole SurfaceHolder thing (It's a pain and usually not needed unless you are making a photo app). The idea in Android is that if you just want a photo, then the Camera App will give you a photo. That way a user could choose which camera app they want to use for the job (by default they have only one). But theoretically if the person had a photo app that intercepted this same intent, and it provided nicer filters than the stock android then they could use it to deliver a pic

Comment: Greg, is there a callback I could implement for the camera close event? Unfortunately my ios skill are basic at most. I am only trying to implement features native to it in android..sorry

Comment: Camera close? Sorry not too sure how that maps. Like I said I could do more if you pointed me at the ios docs that you are using for a reference. Basically what will happen in your app, you call camera, the app opens, the user either takes a photo or hits the back button or cancels the process somehow. If they cancel you will get the RESULT_CANCEL code back. If not then you will get a photo at the URI you used to request the photo to be saved to.

Comment: Thanks Greg!! this is what I needed to know. You have been great help!!

Answer (score 0):

Android provides the some of the callbacks to listen for the Camera events.Those callbacks are declared inside the Camera class.By using those callbacks you can handle the camera events. follow this link..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

Comment: Balaji could you tell me how I could implement onCancel and onFinishPickingMedia events in android? I am desperate!!

Comment: ok, I would like to know which listener I could implement for events like onCancel and onFinishPickingMedia?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

   <receiver
        android:name="com.android.application.CameraEventReciver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```